# How widespread is sailing between Japanese islands in private yachts?

Tags: japan, islands, sailing

In some places of the world where there are large bodies of water there are many people who sail their private boats between villages or islands. Often a traveller can befriend or pay these people to travel on their yachts on motorboats.

For instance I've joined in yacht races on Sydney Harbour, hung out with expats at Marinas in the Mexican Caribbean, and pondered sailing between Panama and Colombia with families who take travellers aboard for a fee.

Now Japan has many islands and I've ridden some ferries there. But I had never stopped to think whether either Japanese or foreigners sail pleasurecraft around the islands of Japan. It seems like a perfect place for it, but perhaps the seas are too difficult or it's just not yet part of the culture there.

So does such a thing exist and might a traveller be able to join some people in some island hopping?

Comment: what would you accept as an answer? Evidence that it happens at all?

Comment: Evidence that it either happens or doesn't happen. Or of the degree to which it happens. It's a good question for anecdotal answers such as "I've done it" or "I've seen it" or "Here's some links to articles or marina websites".

Comment: Do you speak Japanese? Otherwise I would assume you depend on foreigners doing this?

Comment: I only know a sprinkling of Japanese but I enjoy the language barrier and have lots of experience hitchhiking up and down Japan so this doesn't bother me at all. Obviously I don't know any sailing terminology though.

Comment: I would assume other people might be bothered with you not speaking Japanese in this case though...

Comment: Well then those people wouldn't be speaking with me then... I'd still like to know to which degree this kind of inter-island sailing is done.

Comment: It's a nitpick, but it's not "obvious"; if this is an interest of yours, you've done it before, *and* you know even a little Japanese ... (Also, you know how loanwords go, there - granted it's a country/culture with a nautical bent, but still.) // Maybe you could add some supporting information for your prev exp? How did you find these folks in other seas? (and why doesn't that work in .jp?)

Comment: I haven't tried it in Japan yet. I haven't been in island areas and I haven't noticed private sailboats. If I get to Japan on my upcoming trip I shall certainly look for information. I've met sailing types by walking into a marina full of expats in Mexico, eating at a seaside cafe in Greece, through friend-of-a-friend in Sydney, chatting to the person sitting next to me on a flight between Vancouver and Mexico. Then there's hostels with notices up offering transport or seeking help or company on boats. I know this happens in some places, now I want to know if it happens in Japan too.

Answer (score 12):

Take [this view](https://maps.google.com/?ll=35.61907,139.799824&spn=0.081773,0.154324&t=h&z=13) of Tokyo Harbor. Scan around the coastline. You will notice that a vast majority of the property on the ocean is occupied by things related to:

- Manufacturing (Oil, Chemical, Petrochemical especially)
- Shipping (Warehouses, Ports, Airports, etc.)

As you can tell by the coastline, a lot of land gets created artificially to increase the amount of land that has access to the ocean, as it is in great demand for a country that does a lot of international trade, especially by ship. From Chiba to Kanagawa, the coast is virtually 100% occupied.

You can see the same thing around [Kansai's Coast](https://maps.google.com/?ll=34.615692,135.352936&spn=0.331146,0.617294&t=h&z=11) from Wakayama to Himeji.

Because of the demand for oceanfront property by business, something like a marina for pleasure boats is prohibitively expensive for the average person. Unlike less dense countries, there just isn't some empty land near cities to put a boat on. For pleasure craft, you are better off visiting [Lake Biwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Biwa) or the Japan Sea coast of Japan (which is much less densely populated), but neither will do a good job island-hopping.

The only people I have met with pleasure boats around cities in Japan are incredibly wealthy, and are unlikely to invite someone island hopping.

If you go out in to the country, specifically around the [Seto Inland Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seto_Inland_Sea), there are a lot more fishing villages and people with boats, and many of the islands in the Inland Sea can only be reached by boat. The same goes true for [the islands between Kagoshima and Okinawa prefectures](https://maps.google.com/?ll=29.730992,130.46814&spn=2.79507,4.938354&t=m&z=8). Ferries can be infrequent, and the residents of each island can be pretty small (many have less than a thousand people).

The Seto Inland Sea is probably the best bet, as there are more islands and they are far closer together -- you are more likely to be able to find your way somewhere.

In any case, chances are you are going to need some good Japanese if you want to hitchhike on boats as you need to get outside the city. Some of these places are incredibly rural and rarely see non-residents at all, let alone non-Japanese.

If you mean sailing between major islands (like between [Honshu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honshu) and [Kyushu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyushu), the distances tend to be greater and since there is regular ferry or train service across, it is less likely that people are going that way anyway.

Comment: It's normally the wealthy who own sailboats, not just in Japan. It's normal that marinas are scarce and expensive too. Yet the people that sail their own boats seem to be very friendly to foreigners and travellers, not the ones with mega yachts but often self made people whose small yacht might cost the price of a luxury car. Often retired couples or divorced men in their fifties and sixties. So I'm just saying you've come to some conclusions based on your assumptions that would make sense anywhere, yet in my experience there are plenty of friendly people sailing who don't fit this equation.

Comment: Round the UK many individuals have boats - from small dinghies up to millionaire yachts. Of my friends, none of whom are that well off, I think more than thirty have boats.

Comment: I guess I assume that you have to be at least upper middle class to have a yacht/sailboat capable of going between islands. But I don't usually talk about incomes (-;

Comment: If you look around the [Seto Inland Sea](https://maps.google.com/?ll=34.360159,133.572464&spn=0.158429,0.308647&t=m&z=12) you can see that many islands are less than 2 miles apart. You could do them in a canoe in good weather -- serious sailboats are not necessary. This isn't true for the islands around Kagoshima/Okinawa (which are open ocean and slightly more distant). So upper middle class is only necessary around cities, but if your purpose is boating, rent a boat on the Seto Inland Sea and explore!

Comment: I've just discovered that there are at least three [marinas on the main island of Okinawa](http://www.sail-okinawa.com/marinas/) at least. The same website contains this tantalizing fact: "Theoretically, it’s free to keep a boat in a public harbor, although some ports might have a fisherman’s cooperative association that charges a fee."